# No flash message output in console

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have a controller that is hit via an Ajax call and that sets `flash[:info]` to some string. This controller renders some `js.erb` file where I put:

```
console.log("<%= flash["info"] %>")
```

but unfortunately nothing is output in my console. How can I output this message ?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Do you have a redirect in your controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because flash[:info] doesn't equal to flash["info"], you have to use only one type. So this should work:

```
console.log("<%= flash[:info] %>")
```

Comment: Don't know, maybe sawa didn't understand your question correctly

Comment: That only works with redirect in the action!

Comment: @raskhadafi - actually not, this works well on current page too